# Can wifi / geo triggers be invoked even if the Worklight app is not running, including not in the background?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-geolocation

In Android, an app which is not currently running can be notified when certain event happens (like wifi scan results available, boot process completed) through Broadcast Receivers mechanism. Is this possible in anyway so that the wifi/geo triggers can be invoked even if the Worklight app is not running, including not running in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding wifi/connectivity changes notifying your app, that looks possible since it is a standard system event. It would likely take custom native code since you'd need to implement a broadcast receiver. And you'd need to register your receiver in your app's AndroidManifest.xml file. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html and http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-getting-notified-of-connectivity-changes/

Regarding geolocation triggers, it is unclear what sort of triggers you are looking for. This is all I see in the Android docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.html and the standard broadcast actions at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#constants

If you are looking for something like geofencing, it would take application logic to determine when to fire events, so that means an app or service needs to be running. So although your broadcast receiver's onReceive() method can get called upon a geo event, who is going to fire that event?

Answer (score 0):

Having the triggers activate when the application is not running at all (not even in background) isn't supported through the Worklight APIs. 
You could try and use Worklight Android Native SDK together with cmarcelk's suggestions. Or you could use the Worklight Android triggers within a native service, together with the Broadcast Receivers mechanism so that it will run automatically on boot. You could then use an Intent to open the application from the trigger callback.